# Get parent page url to show up when it is in child pages

Tags: links, child-pages

I would like to ask that, how to get the link back to parent page when i'm in the child pages? I would rather to use a proper link instead of `<a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>` method.

**Question & Example:**
How can i get the link of 2nd level child page when i'm in 3rd level child page?

`Home > Parent Page > 1st Level Child Page > 2nd Level Child Page > 3rd Level Child Page`

`Home > Parent Page > 1st Level Child Page(this page link show up) > Current Page`

`Home > Parent Page(this page link show up) > Current Page`

**Updated line:
I have added these three examples above for better explain in what i'm trying to ask.**

This question is not about `breadcrumbs`. I would just like to get the link of parent page to show up when it's in child pages.

And how can i get the link of 1st level child page when i'm in 2nd level child page?

The reason i am asking this question is that i want to create a `Back To Previous Page` link for different level when i'm in different child page. Please tell me if you don't understand.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use something like this to get the parent page URL (and show its page title):

```
<?php if ( $post->post_parent ) { ?>
 <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>" >
    <?php echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); ?>
 </a>
<?php } ?>
```

If you are running this code outside of the loop (thanks [@BorisKuzmanov](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/68965/boris-kuzmanov)), then use this:

```
<?php global $post;
  if ( $post->post_parent ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>" >
    <?php echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent ); ?>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? Where are you putting this code?

Comment: I put this code at the page where I want the link to display. But, it shows nothing.

Comment: Try it on your sidebar.php and see if it works there. It will only show something (the page parent) WHEN the page in question HAS a parent.

Comment: If you are running the code outside a loop, try adding `global $post` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: @BorisKuzmanov, Yes! I have tested again this code. It's working. Thank you!

Comment: If I use either snippet of code on page.php (for example), they both work, both outside of a loop ...should they not? Or does it depend on your setup/theme? And thanks by the way, this is great! :)

Comment: Working , confirm working, and helped me bring the ID of the parent, to make some conditionals I needed to do!!